# Function input types

Tags: haskell

I'm studying Haskell in a subject at university - this a workshop question I've done in my spare time, and as you may guess I am grappling with types in Haskell. I've done the question but without answers being published yet I am left seriously wondering if this is the best way to do it.

Here is a basic representation of HTML, provided in the question

```
type HTML = [HTML_element]
data HTML_element
    = HTML_text String
    | HTML_font Font_tag HTML
    | HTML_p HTML
    | HTML_ul [HTML]
    | HTML_ol [HTML]
data Font_tag = Font_tag (Maybe Int) (Maybe String) (Maybe Font_color)
data Font_color
    = Colour_name String
    | Hex Int
    | RGB Int Int Int
```

The question asks to construct a Haskell function 'num_font_tags' that would count all instances of a font_tag in such an HTML representation. What follows is my answer, which took me about a full hour of butting my head against a wall, but it compiles fine and I believe is a solution:

```
num_font_tags :: HTML -> Int
num_font_tags [] = 0
num_font_tags (x:xs) = num_font_tag_single x + num_font_tags xs

num_font_tags_list :: [HTML] -> Int
num_font_tags_list [] = 0
num_font_tags_list (x:xs) = num_font_tags x + num_font_tags_list xs

num_font_tag_single :: HTML_element -> Int
num_font_tag_single (HTML_text _) = 0
num_font_tag_single (HTML_font _ html) = num_font_tags html
num_font_tag_single (HTML_p html) = num_font_tags html
num_font_tag_single (HTML_ul html) = num_font_tags_list html
num_font_tag_single (HTML_ol html) = num_font_tags_list html
```

Initially I thought I'd only need the first function, but I ran into problems as it only accepts the HTML type, but then I needed two more functions - one to accept the [HTML] type and one to accept the HTML_element type.

Is that seriously how I needed to do this question? Or am I going way overboard by having 3 functions. Can it be done with one? My main question is - am I missing something about Haskell's nature that would make this a lot simpler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need only one such function, the other(s) can be simply reduced to

```
num_font_tag_single :: HTML_element -> Int
```

with `sum` and `map`.

As you have it, you have

```
num_font_tags xs = sum $ map num_font_tag_single xs
```

and

```
num_font_tag_list xs = sum $ map num_font_tags xs
                --   = sum . map num_font_tag_single $ concat xs
```

You could also derive the remaining functions from each of the other two, since you can easily obtain a list from a single value, but in any case you need to at some point inspect a `HTML_element`, so it's best to make `num_font_tag_single` the base on which to build.

You have

```
num_font_tag_single (HTML_font _ html) = num_font_tags html
```

which should be

```
num_font_tag_single (HTML_font _ html) = num_font_tags html + 1
                                                        --  ^^^
```

or you could simplify the function to `num_font_tag_single _ = 0`.

Apart from that, that's basically the only way to do it, whether you name the functions that sum the number of font tags in in a contained list of `HTML_element`s resp. `[HTML]` or use `sum . map num_font_tag_single` resp. `sum . map num_font_tag_single . concat` is up to personal preference mostly, but since the target is a function

```
num_font_tags :: HTML -> Int
```

it's natural to give that a name (and use `num_font_tags . concat` in the recursion).

Comment: Thanks - obviously you know your Haskell. Some questions - how does one "name the functions that sum the number of font tags in in a contained list of HTML_elements resp. [HTML]"? I'm reading through the tutorials as I go but I've seen no mention of that. Also how do you do this "it's natural to give that a name (and use num_font_tags . concat in the recursion)."?

Comment: By that I mean giving the function a name (`num_font_tags`) instead of using `sum . map num_font_tag_single` etc. The decision is whether you define `num_font_tags = sum . map num_font_tag_single` or just use the right-hand-side everywhere. If you use a function often, giving it a name is obviously worth it. For one use, probably not, for two maybe.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was more complicated than that :- ). Also, when you say "You could also derive the remaining functions from each of the other two, since you can easily obtain a list from a single value". Do you mean I could construct num_font_tags as a standalone function without num_font_tags_single? Also what do you mean by obtaining a list from a single value?

Comment: If you have a function `foo :: [SomeType] -> Result`, you can get a function `bar :: SomeType -> Result` from that per `bar x = foo [x]` (obtaining a list from a single value is `x ~> [x]`). So if you have `num_font_tags`, you can get `num_font_tag_single` from that per `num_font_tag_single html_element = num_font_tags [html_element]`. One more layer of lists to get it from `num_font_tag_list`. But of course, defining `num_font_tag_single` is the easiest, since no matter what, you have to pattern-match on the `HTML_element` constructors at some point.

Comment: Perfect - thanks, I was able to get it to work. The reason I asked that last bit is because the question asked to do it for the type signature HTML -> Int, not HTML_element -> Int. You are very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, every problem has a solution that's short, awesome, and incomprehensibly abstract:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Data
import Data.Data.Lens


type HTML = [HTML_element]
data HTML_element
    = HTML_text String
    | HTML_font Font_tag HTML
    | HTML_p HTML
    | HTML_ul [HTML]
    | HTML_ol [HTML]
  deriving (Data, Typeable)

data Font_tag = Font_tag (Maybe Int) (Maybe String) (Maybe Font_color)
  deriving (Data, Typeable)

data Font_color
    = Colour_name String
    | Hex Int
    | RGB Int Int Int
  deriving (Data, Typeable)

instance Plated HTML_element where
  plate = uniplate

isFont :: HTML_element -> Bool
isFont (HTML_font _ _) = True
isFont _               = False

num_font_tags :: HTML -> Int
num_font_tags = length . filter isFont . concatMap universe

num_font_tags2 :: HTML -> Int
num_font_tags2 = lengthOf $ each . parts . each . filtered isFont
```

These use the [Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.8.7.3) package.
The second solution takes the length of a 'fold' obtained by

1. Going through each element of the HTML list.
2. Going through the list of HTML_element subcomponents of each HTML_element, including itself.
3. Going through each HTML_element of every such list.
4. Skipping the ones that aren't HTML_fonts.

The `parts` traversal and `universe` function are only available for data types that are  instances of the `Plated` typeclass. I implemented it with `uniplate`, which needs data types to be instances of `Data` and `Typeable`; those can be derived with the `DeriveDataTypeable` language extension.

Comment: Hey sorry I hadn't responded to your answer. It is a bit too in-depth for me at this point in my Haskell learning (I am a super newbie). Thankyou for responding though